# 500 Server Error for Python in ASP Script

Tags: python, asp-classic, iis-7.5, activepython

The following asp script is giving me the error: "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error"

```
<%@ Language = Python%>
<%
def main():
    Response.Write("My first ASP script!")
main()
%>
```

when I run it on IIS 7.5 Windows 7 (64 bit). In the error log it simply mentions an ASP_0147 error.

I have installed Python 3.2 and Active Python 3.2.2.3 on the server and registered Python via: pyscript.py

I have enabled 32-bit applications for the server. I have also installed Python for Windows to see if that would help.

Can you suggest how I might fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to get this working now for python3 but I have to register with --debug, as follows:

```
C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\axscript\client>c:\Python32\python.exe
 pyscript.py --debug
Requesting elevation and retrying...
Registered: Python (for debugging)
```

Why will it only work in debug mode? Is it safe to run in this mode?

Here's the trace when debug is enabled:

```
Object with win32trace dispatcher created (object=None)
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-SetScriptSite(<PyIActiveScriptSite at 0x00000000036923B0 with obj at 0x000000000056FFD8>,) [1,0,None]
Debugging extensions (axdebug) module does not exist - debugging is disabled.. 
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._QueryInterface_ with unsupported IID IActiveScriptProperty ({4954E0D0-FBC7-11D1-8410-006008C3FBFC})
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-InitNew() [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-GetScriptDispatch(None,) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._QueryInterface_ with unsupported IID {1D044690-8923-11D0-ABD2-00A0C911E8B2} ({1D044690-8923-11D0-ABD2-00A0C911E8B2})
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('Response', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('Request', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('Server', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('Session', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('Application', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('ObjectContext', 66) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('ASPGLOBALTLB', 74) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-ParseScriptText('def main():\r\n    Response.Write("My first ASP script!")\r\nmain()\r\n', None, None, 'STRIP EMBEDDED HTML COMMENTS', 0, 1, 192, 0) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-GetScriptDispatch(None,) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-AddNamedItem('ScriptingNamespace', 10) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-SetScriptState(1,) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-SetScriptState(0,) [1,0,None]
in <win32com.axscript.client.pyscript.PyScript object at 0x00000000035946A0>._InvokeEx_-Close() [1,0,None]
```

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: The enable 32 bit applications is a setting on the application pool, but only relevant if your server is 64 bit. Does a similar piece of vbscript code run correctly?

Comment: Your ASP has `Response.Write("My first ASP script!")`, but your debug trace shows `Response.Write("My third ASP script!")\r\n`. Can you check if it is the same page or different page.

Comment: @user568109 Sorry both have the same message. I've fixed this above!

Comment: @Baz I test my solution and it work fine with Python 3.2 and Active Python 3.2.2.3 on IIS 7.5 Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: @Baz I was wondering have you any chance to try the solution?

Comment: @Kambiz Shahim Thanks very much for your answer! I will try it soon when I have get a chance!

Answer (score 5):

May not be the appropriate solution, in the past I've had this problem. 
The recent versions of activepython seems broken for active scripting. 
I was able just the version 2.5.6.10. 
If the version is not important, you could try that older version.

Comment: I have read something about this but I still managed to get it to work on my windowsXP machine with Python 3.2.

Comment: Although I must admit that if I browse within IIS Manager on my windows machine, I get the 500 Error if I try to load my page. I then need to restart iis for this website in order for the page to work again.

Comment: I understand. All my attempts was on Windows 7. I had give up :) You can try to register with `pyscript.py --debug` and trace using Pythonwin.exe. Maybe you can find something.

Comment: Installed Active Python 2.5.6.10 on the server at now it works as expected. Does anyone know of a fix to get it to work for 3.2? Thanks!

Comment: I installed 2.7 and ran "python pyscript.py --uninstall" on the 2.5 version before registering the 2.7 version instead. Uninstalling states that 2.5 is uninstalled. Printing sys.version_info from my asp page gives me (2, 5, 6, 'final', 0). So what does pyscript.py do? I'm confused...

Comment: You could try installing the latest version of pywin32 manually maybe

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `trace` method and `print` statements in the `win32comext\axscript\client\framework.py`  because in the COM components writing to the `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` like the `print` statement causes an exception for example `trace("Debugging extensions (axdebug) module does not exist - debugging is disabled..")` at the line 572 of `framework.py` causes an exception.

One workaround is adding `import win32traceutil` in the `framework.py`. The `win32traceutil` redirects output to `win32trace remote collector` and solve the problem without need to enabling debugging witch cause performance issues.

Another workaround is redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to null, you can add following code snippet at the top of `framework.py`.

```
  f = open('nul', 'w')
  sys.stdout = f
  sys.stderr = f
```

**UPDATE: The root cause and the solution**

There is already a mechanism in `framework.py` to prevent print and trace statements to raise an exception but the problem is in the `write` method of `SafeOutput` class. When tracing and debugging is not enabled, in the write method an exception occurs and `win32api.OutputDebugString` in the except clause will invoke with the wrong encoding which cause an exception. Because the `win32api.OutputDebugString` accept Unicode string not a multibyte character set (MBCS) as an argument.

The solution:

in the `win32comext\axscript\client\framework.py` in the `SafeOutput` class

```
class SafeOutput:
softspace=1
def __init__(self, redir=None):
    if redir is None: redir = sys.stdout
    self.redir=redir
def write(self,message):
    try:
        self.redir.write(message)
    except:
        win32api.OutputDebugString(message.encode('mbcs'))
def flush(self):
    pass
def close(self):
    pass
```

just change

```
win32api.OutputDebugString(message.encode('mbcs'))  # ANSI Enconding
```

to

```
win32api.OutputDebugString(message) # Unicode
```